# Specify OpenMP to GCC

Tags: c, gcc, openmp

For OpenMP, when my code is using the functions in its API (for example, omp_get_thread_num()) without using its directives (such as those #pragma omp ...),

1. why directly specifying libgomp.a to
   gcc instead of using -fopenmp
   doesn't work, such as

   ```
   gcc hello.c /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4/libgomp.a  -o hello
   ```

   **Update:** I just found that linking to libgomp.a does not work, but linking to libgomp.so works. Does it mean OpenMP can not be static linked?
2. Why -fopenmp only works without
   specifying the library files

   ```
   gcc hello.c -fopenmp -o hello
   ```

   **Update:** In other words, when using -fopenmp, why explicit linking to libgomp.so is not required?
3. Why does this also compile:

   ```
   gcc hello.c -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4/ -lgomp -o hello
   ```

   Will this ignore OpenMP directives
   in the code if there is any?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: From GCC documentation: -fopenmp flag also arranges for automatic linking of the OpenMP runtime library. See here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/Enabling-OpenMP.html#Enabling-OpenMP

Answer (score 32):

In general, keep in mind that the directives and the functions are different things; the former are controlled by `-fopenmp` and the latter are controlled by linking to the OpenMP library.

1. (**Updated to incorporate comments**) Try using the `-fopenmp` and `-static` options to statically link OpenMP. Because this implies `-lgomp -lrt`, the following command won't compile correctly unless you also specify the location of `librt.a`.

   ```
   gcc hello.c /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4/libgomp.a  -o hello
   ```
2. (**Updated to incorporate comments**) I imagine that the following command is compiling correctly because the OpenMP library is already in your library path and your system's dynamic linker is automatically linking with `libgomp.so`.

   ```
   gcc hello.c -fopenmp -o hello
   ```
3. The following command is probably compiling properly because it is linking to the shared object for OpenMP (`libgomp.so`). Note that the `-static` option is *not* used.

   ```
   gcc hello.c -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4/ -lgomp -o hello
   ```

   If you don't specify the `-fopenmp` option, OpenMP directives should be ignored.

Comment: Thanks! I am considering the code with API and without directives. (1) I just found that linking to libgomp.a does not work, but linking to libgomp.so works. Does it mean OpenMP can not be static linked? (2) when using -fopenmp, why explicit linking to libgomp.so is not required?

Comment: (1) You can statically link OpenMP by using "-fopenmp -static".  What you will find is that when this is specified it uses "-lgomp -lrt".  (2) If the system supports the dynamic linker then it is used and when you specify -fopenmp it will link with libgomp.so.

Comment: It seems both the compiler and the linker requires the `-fopenmp` flag.

Comment: @ejd Hi, I would like to know how can people know "-fopenmp -static" links to openmp and rt libraries. I do `man gcc` and search `-fopenmp -static` but not found result, and search `-fopenmp` not get result of `rt` library.