# Is it possible to expand GCC/Clang compile and link options that start with "-f"?

Tags: c++, compilation, linker

I write C/C++ with GCC/Clang, but know little about compiler options that starts with "-f".

For example, to turn on Address Sanitizer, I pass "-fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address" to the compiler. This should both affect compile and link stages.

Another example, to turn on OpenMP, I pass "-fopenmp" to the compiler, which gives support of compile and link to shared openmp library.

If I use static openmp library, I should pass "-fopenmp" to the compiler, and pass "-fopenmp -static" to the linker. And [this StackOverFlow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6353399/2999096) says it means "-lgomp -lrt".

My question: is there any method to expand the "-f" started compile/options, thus I can know what exactly libraries this "-f" flag links to?

Comment: The `-f` prefix just means *flag*. That big group of Boolean options can do a lot a different things.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/16227501

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's check the docs of clang at https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html `--verbose` or `-v` looks very promising.
A [quick check at compiler-explorer.com](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/6Eao973xc) gives promising results.

GCC has a similar page with all options: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html
Here we have `-v` as well, though as it prints stuff to stderr, I can't verify the output at compiler-explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so - this is not normalized - the two examples that you cite are sizable extensions to `gcc` that do things their own way.

But you can check the final executable with `ldd` - you will see the linked-in libraries.